# Excel VBA: Array return of size 1 fills entire calling formula

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I find that a user-defined array formula function behaves counter to my expectations when the length or width of the return is 1.

Below is a simple function that populates the calling array formula region with values from `fillValue`.  The extent to which the area is filled is given by the first two input parameters

```
Public Function arrayFill(numRows As Integer, numColumns As Integer, fillValue As Variant) As Variant
Dim returnArray() As Variant
ReDim returnArray(1 To numRows, 1 To numColumns)
    For i = 1 To numRows
        For j = 1 To numColumns
            returnArray(i, j) = fillValue
            Debug.Print "Filling (" & i & "," & j & ") with " & fillValue
        Next
    Next
arrayFill = returnArray
End Function
```

### Case 1:  Size greater than 1: Behavior is as expected

Below is the response when I enter `{=arrayFill(3,2,"Fill-Text")}` into an array formula spanning B2:E6.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qcJM.png

### Case 2:  One dimension of length 1: Formula response fills entire dimension

Below is the response when I enter `{=arrayFill(1,2,"Fill-Text")}` into the same array.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqkt8.png

My expected and desired result is for only a row of 2 cells to be populated in this instance.  It's strange that the fill value is extended to all rows, considering the debug print in the immediate window only reveals the following

```
Filling (1,1) with Fill-Text
Filling (1,2) with Fill-Text
```

If I give 1,1 as my first two parameters, the entire array formula region will be filled.  Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a VBA issue so much as how Excel handles array formulas. It is easy enough to reproduce the sort of thing that you are observing with the built-in Transpose() function.

The following link has a nice discussion of how Excel deals with size mismatches in array formulas:

http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeedj.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your situation is that you wish to have something like an ArrayFunction that fills a (pre-selected) Range, but which should put #na's when the selected Range is too big (has more elements compared to the array you have created in your function).

However, as the "mysteries of MS" would have it, if the length of the actual array is 1, and the pre-selected range > 1 cell, then MS's infinite wisdom decides to "fill" the array/range with that "effective scalar" (this is primarily a result of how MS treats intrinsic array func's like SumProduct(), etc).

To obviate this "problem" with user defined array funcs, assuming FArray() is a "normal" array of any type (e.g. Double, etc), but with length determined during the computation, the following works for me (basically make a "fake" array of length 2, with the second "fake" element a VBA #na):

```
Function UserArrFunc() as Variant
    '
    ' do some calcs that return FArray(), and its length, n
    '
    If( n = 1) Then
       '
       ' special processing for length 1
       '
       Dim ScalarVar as Variant
       '
       ScalarVar = CVar(FArray(1))
       '
       UserArrFunc = Array(ScalarVar, CVErr(xlErrNA))
       '
    Else
       '
       ' normal processing
       '
       UserArrFunc = Array(FArray)
       '
    End IF
    '
End Function ' UserArrFunc
```

This should put #na's in all the "spare" cells in the selected range even if FArray() is length 1.

To be extra certain, MS uses the word "array" in many many different ways, sometimes referring to "normal" arrays (e.g. as us math geeks might), but sometimes using the word to mean all manner of different things.  For example, the intrinsic function Array() used above is a "casting" mechanism to manage Variant/SafeArray "types".  So, much care is required in "understanding" what MS has in mind.  For example, if you tried the same thing as above but with ScalarVar being an array itself, then the resulting content of UserArrFunc will be fundamentally different, requiring a whole new discussion.